# How to change media player of my custom receiver chromecast(CAF) for another player

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have a custom receiver chromecast(CAF) and I need change media player for another player (Bitmovin player), but I don't know how to do. There are any documentation about this?

Comment: You should probably tell us what resources you've attempted to find and why they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

When you're developing a Chromecast receiver, you have a few different options you can take when building out the UI and functionality. You can find an overview of the different options [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver#styled_media_receiver).

Google recommends that you use the provided `cast-media-player` element to handle the player, as it integrates with senders and the Chromecast UI nicely.

However, you mentioned you plan to integrate with the Bitmovin player, so after a quick Google search, I found [this documentation from Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/bitmovin-video-player-chromecast/). It should be noted that the example provided in that link uses version 2 of the CAF receiver framework, which is now deprecated.

Your best bet will be to reach out to Bitmovin and ask if their player supports the CAF receiver framework v3 - or if they have a skeleton app for you to use.

If that falls through you are going to need to write all the bindings to listen to sender events, player events, handling DRM, updating the UI manually, etc. If you decide to go down this path, a good starting point in Google's documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/core_features#creating-a-customized-receiver-app).